# How to change uri value of Video component dynamically

Tags: react-native

I am working with react native, and I am using a video component from the expo. during this how I can change the value for URI attribute dynamically

Comment: Can you show the code and what you tried ?

Comment: actually I got the solution my self. now I am facing a new problem, is there is any way to play a youtube video with video component. I see suggestions  regarding youtube component, but there is no reference regarding this component in official doumentation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As you mentioned in the comment that you already solved the problem and want to play youtube videos)

You can use WebView to play Youtube video.

Working demo: https://snack.expo.io/Syhzx-VvX

Here is the sample code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, WebView, Platform } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  render() {
    return (
     <View style={{ height: 300 }}>
        <WebView
                style={ styles.WebViewContainer }
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4' }}
         />

     </View>

   );
  }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  WebViewContainer: {
    marginTop: (Platform.OS == 'android') ? 20 : 0,
  }
});
```

Otherwise if you don't want to use WebView, use a third party package like [react-native-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube)